# Enable WiFi when a specific application needs it, then disable after N minutes

Tags: wi-fi, automation, ankidroid

I do not leave WiFi nor data transfer enabled on my Samsung Note 3. The only application that I would like to have access to the network is [Ankidroid](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/).

**Is there any way to have WiFi automatically enabled when Ankidroid requests network access, and then have WiFi automatically disabled (perhaps after N minutes)?**

Right now I am enabling Wifi, syncing Ankidroid, and then disabling Wifi manually. It would be nice to automate at least part of this process.

Comment: is Ankidroid runs as a service which tries to access the wifi? or if it runs in foreground i.e., when application is launched on clicked it? if it falls in second case, there is some hope to automate using Tasker

Comment: @Cyborgz: Thank you, in fact Ankidroid does not run as a service. I open Ankidroid manually. However, I would prefer that the WiFi be turned off while I'm using Ankidroid and only enabled for the brief few seconds when Ankidroid must sync. Ankidroid is usually used with the network disconnected, and only needs to sync when I first start the app, and when I'm done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Good. In this case you may try Tasker from App Store (However there are free trail available). Set your profile that triggers when the Specific App (Ankidroid) is Opened, and write a simple task

Proile:
1. App-> Ankidroid

Task:
1. Enable WIFI
2. Wait N Seconds
3. Disable WIFI

Tasker need some learning curve though, but it is very powerful and you can automate anything in your phone!